# Sending `Encrypted Extension` and `Server Finished` in one handshake message. Is it mandatory in TLS1.3?

Tags: ssl, cryptography, tls1.3

As per `RFC 8446` (TLSv1.3) [https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446]

`Encrypted Extension` and `Finished` are two different handshake messages.

But in RFC 8448 (Example Handshake Traces for TLS 1.3) [https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8448]

In all examples of this trace document, `Encrypted Extension` (message type 0x08) and `Server Finished`
(message type 0x14) messages are concatenated and send together.

Refer page number 23 and 24 of RFC 8446.

```
payload (80 octets):  **08** 00 00 28 00 26 00 0a 00 14 00 12 00 1d 00
         17 00 18 00 19 01 00 01 01 01 02 01 03 01 04 00 1c 00 02 40 01
         00 00 00 00 00 2a 00 00 **14** 00 00 20 48 d3 e0 e1 b3 d9 07 c6 ac
         ff 14 5e 16 09 03 88 c7 7b 05 c0 50 b6 34 ab 1a 88 bb d0 dd 1a
         34 b2
```

I know by adding two handshake messages (if they are sent by one entity immediately one after other) together will increase performance and RFC 8446 provide this provision.

But is this really mandatory by any server implementation to send `Encrypted Extension` and `Server Finished` messages together?

Or Server and Client should support both implementations i.e.

a) Sending `Encrypted Extension` and `Server Finished` messages separately one by one.

b) Sending `Encrypted Extension` and `Server Finished` message together in one handshake message.

Comment: Probably better asked at [IT security](https://security.stackexchange.com) as this contains no programming challenge.

Answer (score 2):

TLS is send over TCP. TCP is a byte stream which has no concept of messages and thus has no concept of "messages send together" too. Two `send` at the application level or from within the TLS stack might end up within the same TCP packet the same as one `send` might be spread over multiple TCP packets.

In other words: since the TCP layer underlying TLS is only a byte stream which can be packetized in arbitrary ways not controlled by the upper layer, it would be impossible to follow a mandatory requirement of sending multiple TLS messages in the same TCP packet.

Comment: Sometimes a lower API for TCP connections is provided (unfortunately?). So this is completely right ..... in principle.

Comment: @Maarten-reinstateMonica: This question was about the standard is __mandating__ to put multiple TLS messages into a single TCP packet.  All I said is that it is impossible to __mandate__ such message/packet oriented semantics for  TCP and not that no TLS stack might __implement__ such semantics. TCP is defined as a byte stream with no defined relation between "message" boundaries and packets, no matter if a particular implementation might allow such control.

Comment: I agree that they *should* not implement such semantics, but I have seen implementations that use a low level TCP API that do simply assume that messages are contained in the same packet and it is easy to make that mistake if you're programming it yourself, hence the comment. Let's just say that it is something that I would *test*.

Comment: @Maarten-reinstateMonica: I fully agree that are implementations out there which make the wrong assumptions since the authors did not understand TCP. It then sometimes works on localhost but not on the local network due to different MTU. stackoverflow is full of questions where OP wrongly assume that a single `recv` matches exactly a single `send` with TCP.